# How can I update my start datetime and endtime using datetime-local input?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to update my event details and I have edited the code already so that it can get the data from the database and display it in a modal so that a user can edit it the problem is my start datetime and end datetime doesn't display when I use input type datetime-local that's why I have resorted to using input type text but for the user experience that really isn't the best way to go about it how do i edit the code so that it can display properly

[image]
This is my modal for editing here I used input type text and it displays the correct data
[image]
when I change my input type to datetime-local the data wont display
[image]

EventController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        //

         $this->validate($request, [
            'event_name' => 'required|string|min:2|max:255',
            'daterange' => 'required',
        ]);
        $time_start = $request->input('start_time');

        $time_end = $request->input('end_time');

        $tempDate = $request->input('daterange');
        $temp2 = str_replace('-', null, $tempDate);
        $temp2 = str_replace('/', '-', $temp2);
        $temp3 = explode('  ', $temp2);


        $date1 = date_create_from_format('m-d-Y', $temp3[0]);
        $date2 = date_create_from_format('m-d-Y', $temp3[1]);

        $event = new event([
            'event_name' => $request->input('event_name'),
            'event_desc' => $request->input('event_desc'),
            'event_venue' => $request->input('event_venue'),
            'event_start' => date_format($date1, 'Y-m-d'),
            'event_finish' => date_format($date2, 'Y-m-d'),
            'event_venue' => $request->input('event_venue'),
            'evcat_id' => $request->input('evcat_id'),
            'user_id' => $request->input('user_id'),
        ]);

        $event->save();
        Session::flash('success', 'Event Created Successfully');
        return redirect()->route('event.sched');

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        /**
        $validator = $request->validate([
            'event_name' => 'required',
            'event_start' => 'required',
            'event_finish' => 'required',

        ]);



        return redirect()->route('event.sched');
        **/

        $ev = event::find($id);

        $ev->event_name = $request->input("event_name");
        $ev->event_desc = $request->input("event_desc");
        $ev->event_venue = $request->input("event_venue");
        $ev->event_start = $request->input("event_start");
        $ev->event_finish = $request->input("event_finish");

        $ev->save();

        Session::flash('success', 'Event successfully updated.');



        return redirect()->route('event.sched');

    }
```

my blade file

```
@foreach ($event as $ev)
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        {{$ev->event_name}}
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        {{$ev->event_start}}
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        {{$ev->event_finish}}
                                                                    </td>

                                                                    <td>
                                                                        {{$ev->event_status}}
                                                                    </td>

                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#eventModal{{$ev->id}}" data-whatever="{{$ev->id}}">  View</button>

                                                                        <div class="modal fade" id="eventModal{{$ev->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="eventModalLabel{{$ev->id}}">
                                                                            <div class="modal-dialog modal modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                                                                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="eventModalLabel{{$ev->id}}">Event Details:</h4>
                                                                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                                                                    </div>

                                                                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                                                                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('event.update', $ev->id) }}">
                                                                                            @method('PATCH')
                                                                                            @csrf
                                                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                                                        <label for="event-name" class="control-label">Event Name:</label>
                                                                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="event_name" value="{{$ev->event_name}}">
                                                                                                    </div>


                                                                                                </div>



                                                                                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                                                        <label for="event-venue" class="control-label">Venue:</label>
                                                                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="event_venue" value="{{$ev->event_venue}}">
                                                                                                    </div>


                                                                                                </div>

                                                                                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                                                        <label for="event-start" class="control-label">Start Time:</label>
                                                                                                        <input input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="event_start" value="{{$ev->event_start}}">
                                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                                </div>


                                                                                            </div>

                                                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                                                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                                                                        <label for="event-finish" class="control-label">End Time:</label>
                                                                                                        <input input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="event_finish" value="{{$ev->event_finish}}">
                                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                                </div>
                                                                                            </div>

                                                                                        </div>


                                                                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                                                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Edit">
                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                    </form>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` for `input` of type `datetime-local` should be in `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm` format.

So, for example, your `2019-10-04 00:00:00` should become `2019-10-04T00:00`

```php
$date_to_show = date('Y-m-d\TH:i', strtotime('2019-10-04 00:00:00'));//2019-10-04T00:00
```